# no tables loaded in hive or impala

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, impala, cloudera-cdh

Im using CDH5 on Centos 6.5, when I browse to Query Editors > Hive or Impala the table section on the left sits there with with a waiting spinner. There are tables in available as I can query them from the hive cli, and it never loads the tables, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a cookbook solution, i would take the following actions

1. Make sure Hive can list the tables and query values from the hive shell, if not reconfigure hive until you see them
2. Make sure impala-shell can list the tables and query values, if not reconfigure impala until you see them
3. repeat stages 1 and 2 for the Hue query editors

TRIVIAL NOTE: More data about the actual error might be found in the logs of the subsystems